# How to use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to create a collapse/extend list

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using ReactJS to create a collapse/extend list with animation. You can check out the code from https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/qjRKXE. When the user click on the `Extend` button at the top, the list should be shown within 1 second and at the mean time the `footer` should be moved to the bottom. My current code doesn't work very well. First, the list items are not shown with the correct animation style. It seems that all items are rendered at the same time. Second, the footer component move to the bottom immediately after I click `extend` button. How can I implement the list correctly with reactjs animation?

See the Pen [React Animation Demo](https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/qjRKXE/) by joey ([@zhaoyi0113](https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Below is the reactjs code I am using:

```
const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;


const Container = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items:  ['Click', 'To', 'Remove', 'An', 'Item'],
            extend: false
        };
    },

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="animation-container">
                <div onClick={() => this.expendItems()} className="item">
                    {this.state.extend?'Collapse':'Extend'}
                </div>
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
                        {this.renderItems()}
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

                    <div>Footer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    renderItems() {
        const items = this.state.extend? this.state.items: [];

        console.log('render items ', items);
        return items.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={item} className="item">
                    {item}
                </div>
            );  
        }); 
    },

    expendItems() {
        this.setState({extend: !this.state.extend});
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(<Container/>, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way ReactCSSTransitionGroup all components render at the same time.

Moreover, you had the wrong initial translation values, you want to transition from negative values to 0, so that it seems like the buttons are sliding down from the under the expand button

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-sarif;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: $color6;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animation-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.item {
    background-color: $color3;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: mix(black, $color3, 60%);
    position: relative;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
div > .item {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.example-enter {
    top: -240px;
}
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    top: 0px;
    transition: top 1s ease;
}
.example-leave {
    top: 0px;
    transition: top 1s ease;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    top: -240px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gvrgqm

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know how to make the component show one by one instead of showing them all together?

Comment: Yeah, I've just updated the answer with something that might just work @ZhaoYi

Comment: it works great. Did you update the css or javascript for that?